# replace one object with another -Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm aware this muct a very common question, however I tried sources and most of them provide answers with some libraries, ES6 or some methods that native js does not support. I want to purely replace one object with another based on a condition- no ES6, no `clone` and no `copy`.

in the below case: i want to get the value from `subObj` and replace them with the values in `Obj1`

ex: key attributes "key2" and "key3" to be replaced from the values present in the subObj

```
Obj1 = {
"key1" : {values:[1, 2, 44, 505]},
"key2" : {values:[91, 25, 44, 5995]},
"key3" : {values:[1, 24, 44, 595]},
"key4" : {values:[17, 28, 44, 559]}
}

subObj = {

**"key2" : {values:[3, 3, 3, 444]},** // add this one 
**"key3" : {values:[1, 0, 0, 0]}**

}
```

so the output looks like:

```
Obj1 = {
"key1" : {values:[1, 2, 44, 505]},
**"key2" :{ values:[3, 3, 3, 444]},**
**"key3" : {values:[1, 0, 0, 0]},**
"key4" : {values:[17, 28, 44, 559]}
}
```

so far i have tried this:

```
  somefunc: function(condition) {

          if (condition) {
            Object.keys(Obj1).forEach(function(key) { Obj[key] = Obj1[key]});
            return Obj1;
          }
          return Obj;
        },
```

this does not work as expected, any help here?
thx

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm guessing bold tags, OP, what do you mean by `o/p`? Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: @all: Please correct if im worng, isnt object.assign and spread operator all ES6 notations ? as I mentioned above I Cannot use ES6, so these wont work right?

Comment: "ES6 or some methods that native js does not support" - I'm wondering if there's some confusion here as to what ES6 actually is? ES6, also known as ES2015, was released a full 5 years ago and is natively supported in all modern browsers (plus all recent versions of NodeJS etc). Some features of more recent versions of JavaScript (ES2016..ES2020) are sometimes lumped in with ES6 - in this broader usage, it basically just means "modern JavaScript". Generally, you shouldn't worry about which ES version you're using, as long as you're transpiling with something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: we're not using babel, so this wont work, our framework is EXTJs old version and currently no support for ES6, this is not due to browser support, our app fremawork does not supoort

Comment: @user1234 Fair enough (never heard of EXTJs, I assume it's something legacy-ish as the Wikipedia page mentions "DHTML"?). Adding Babel into your build tool chain would require a little dev work up front but might end up saving you a lot of headaches later on, assuming you're building something substantial.

Comment: @LionelRowe: could be, but that is not the solution for now. This is for business not personal projects so cannot take decisions on my own.. :)

Comment: Thanks All for your help and support and the suggested answers...it helped a lottt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function merge(Obj1, subObj) {
    const result = {};

    Object.keys(Obj1).forEach((key) => {
        result[key] = Obj1[key]
    })

    Object.keys(subObj).forEach((k) => {
        if(result[k]){
            console.log('update')
            result[k] = subObj[k]
        } else {
            console.log("add")
            result[k] = subObj[k]
        }
    })

    console.log(result)
    return result
}

merge(Obj1, subObj)
```

Comment: cannot be Es6 sorry..:(

Comment: How bout creating a function that accepts both objects.

Comment: Editing the answer basic function declaration that accepts both objects as parameters. Populates and then cross-references.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
// ...

if (condition) {
    return Object.assign(Obj1, subObj);
}

// ...
```

Comment: isnt Object.assign ES6?

Answer (score 1):

This is what we use the spread operator for

```js
const Obj1 = {
"key1" : {values:[1, 2, 44, 505]},
"key2" : {values:[91, 25, 44, 5995]},
"key3" : {values:[1, 24, 44, 595]},
"key4" : {values:[17, 28, 44, 559]}
}

const subObj = {

"key2" : {values:[3, 3, 3, 444]},
"key3" : {values:[1, 0, 0, 0]}

}

console.log({ ...Obj1, ...subObj });
```

Comment: cannot be Es6 sorry..:(